# AgGrid Grid Options / Default Column Definitions not working on one component

Tags: angular, angular-material, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Typical AG-Grid configuration using Angular

```
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid
                     id="agGrid"
                     class="ag-theme-balham app-aggrid"
                     [rowData]="rowData"
                     [columnDefs]="colDefs"
                     [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                     [multiSortKey]="multiSortKey"
                     (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
                     rowSelection="multiple"
                     (columnResized)="onColumnResized($event)"
                     (gridSizeChanged)="onGridSizeChanged($event)">
    </ag-grid-angular>
```

```
agTableInit() {

    this.gridOptions = {
      pagination: true,
      paginationAutoPageSize: true,
      context: this,
      headerHeight: 75,
      defaultColDef: {
        resizable: true,
        sortable: true,
        filter: true,
      },
    }
    this.colDefs = [
      {
        headerName: 'ID', field: 'id',
        hide: true,
      },
      ...
    ];
```

And the defaultColDef is not being applied to the grid.
As a result, I have no sorting, filtering or pagination enabled.
I can see the tags via Inspect, but all have 'ag-hidden' tags applied

Other pages setup in the same way are working fine, so I'm at a loss to explain why this is happening. No errors in the console logs either...

Answer (score 0):

After posting I realized the issue.
For this particular component, we were calling agTableInit() in a client subscribe, which meant that the onGridReady() was getting called first, with out the full definitions being set (that were being retrieved from they query)

laid the code out slightly differently, and all is working again.